# Como modelar um sistema de comentários

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, modelagem

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Rails. Gostaria de saber como modelar a parte de comentários. Há uma tabela para as chamadas( sistema Helpdesk ), e a mesma se relaciona com a tabela de histórico, que são os comentários. Minha dúvida é, como posso fazer com que eu descubra quem fez um comentário, pois a tabela de chamadas se relaciona com a tabela de chamada_funcionarios, e com a tabela de usuários, e eu preciso filtrar quem comentou.

Comment: Você já possui parte da estrutura pronta pelo que você descreveu. Vou colocar a imagem de uma estrutura simples: http://postimg.org/image/ejjvte03r/  Existe quatro tabelas: chamada / histórico / usuario / chamada_historico, chamada_historico "linka" os historicos as chamadas, e com o id do historico você pode recuperar o usuário depois. É só a ideia, falta implementação, pois não sei como está a **SUA** estrutura atual. _Espero que **eu** tenha entendido corretamente sua necessidade também._

Answer (score 1):

A sua tabela de histórico também precisa ter o id do Usuário que fez o comentário. Após isso, acrescente um `belongs_to :usuario` (por exemplo).

Para relacionar a tabela `chamada` com a tabela `usuario`, usando a tabela `chamada_funcionarios` para relacioná-las, por exemplo, você precisa acrescentar essa relação no model `Chamada` (`has_one :usuario, through: :chamada_funcionarios`).

Feitas essas relações, você pode consultar o autor do chamado pelo model `Chamada` e o autor dos comentários pelo model `Historico`.

Por exemplo:

```ruby
chamada = Chamada.first
comentarios = chamada.historicos
puts "Chamada #{chamada.id}:"
puts "Autor: #{chamada.usuario.nome}"

comentarios.each do |comentario|
  puts "Comentário #{comentario.id}"
  puts "Autor do comentário: #{comentario.usuario.nome}"
end
```